# Hide text that goes beyond width of TD

Tags: html, css

I have a TD with a fixed width in pixels. Despite the width of the TD being set, and the following css applied to the TD, my text is going beyond the width of the TD (I don't want the text to wrap), whereas, I want anything beyond the width of the TD to be hidden.

Here is the CSS I have in place at the moment:

```
td { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:100px !important; }
```

Comment: I think this should work. Can you post the html as well?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ is a good way of showing us where the problem is.
A `<td>` by it's very nature, is affected by the elements around it, and one css definition isn't enough to get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap everything inside the `td` in a `div`, and give that the same rules.

```
td, div { overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:100px !important; }
```